# Unexpected "recursive value needs type" compile error (triggered by local implicits)

Tags: scala

I just encountered an unexpected compile error "recursive value xx needs type".  Trying to simplify, I came up with the following code that doesn't compile with Scala 2.12.3:

```
class Wrapped[A](val inner: A)(implicit val ctag: ClassTag[A]){
  type Inner = A
  def classInfo: String = ctag.toString
}
object Implicits {
  val W = new Wrapped(1234)
  implicit val InnerSeq: Seq[W.Inner] = Seq(1,2)
  implicit val InnerSet: Set[W.Inner] = Set(1,2) // Error: recursive value W needs type
}
```

I would assume that the type of `W` is well defined. But it seems that due to the type `W` occurring in the return type of the local implicit values, `W` is considered recursive even if the implicits are not used in creation of `W`.

The strange thing is that removing the second value `InnerSet` makes the code compile. So one implicit val referring `W.Inner` is OK, while two or more is a no-go.

Removing the implicit `ClassTag` dependency for the Wrapper also makes the code compile.

It is easy to get around the problem by moving W to a separate trait, but it would be good to know what's going on here. Why does the code compile with only one implicit in scope?

**Update:**

In the last preview version of Dotty, the compiler behaves more consistently and doesn't allow any implicits referring W.inner in scope at all:

```
[error] -- [E045] Syntax Error: 
[error] 9 |  implicit val InnerSeq: Seq[W.Inner] = Seq(1,2)
[error]   |                             ^
[error]   |                             cyclic reference involving value W
[error] one error found
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to the scope of the local implicits you've defined, how type inference works and how implicit resolution works. If we look at the output of the typer phase (using `Ytyper-debug`), we see:

```
|-- new Wrapped(1234) EXPRmode (site: value W  in Implicits)
|    |-- new Wrapped BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value W  in Implicits)
|    |    |-- new Wrapped EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (silent: value W  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |-- Wrapped FUNmode-TYPEmode (silent: value W  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |    \-> Wrapped
|    |    |    \-> Wrapped[A]
|    |    \-> (inner: A)(implicit ctag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])Wrapped[A]
|    |-- 1234 BYVALmode-EXPRmode-POLYmode (site: value W  in Implicits)
|    |    \-> Int(1234)
|    solving for (A: ?A)
|    [search #1] start `(inner: A)(implicit ctag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])Wrapped[A]`, searching for adaptation to pt=scala.reflect.ClassTag[Int] (silent: value W  in Implicits) implicits disabled
|    |-- Seq[W.Inner] TYPEmode (site: value InnerSeq  in Implicits)
|    |    |-- scala.`package` EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (site: value InnerSeq  in Implicits)
|    |    |    \-> scala.type
|    |    |-- W.Inner TYPEmode (site: value InnerSeq  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |-- W EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (site: value InnerSeq  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |    |-- new Wrapped(1234) EXPRmode (site: value W  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- new Wrapped BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value W  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- new Wrapped EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (silent: value W  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> Wrapped[A]
|    |    |    |    |    |    \-> (inner: A)(implicit ctag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])Wrapped[A]
|    |    |    |    |    solving for (A: ?A)
|    |    |    |    |    [search #2] start `(inner: A)(implicit ctag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])Wrapped[A]`, searching for adaptation to pt=scala.reflect.ClassTag[Int] (silent: value W
isabled
|    |    |    |    |    |-- Set[W.Inner] TYPEmode (site: value InnerSet  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- W.Inner TYPEmode (site: value InnerSet  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- W EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (site: value InnerSet  in Implicits)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    caught scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving value W: while typing W
```

The typer first has to figure out the type parameter of `A` of `Wrapper`, since we haven't provided an explicit type, the compiler treats it as `Wrapper[A]`. The compiler sees that you require an implicit `ClassTag[A]` in scope to create an instance of `Wrapper`, so implicit resolution kicks in. The Scala compiler will begin with implicits at the local scope, which are `InnerSeq` and `InnerSet`, as you've defined. Continuing the implicit search, the compiler look at `InnerSeq` and tries to see if it a fit for the resolution of type `A` and it's corresponding `ClassTag[A]`, but `InnerSeq` is defined in terms of `W.Inner`, thus the compiler has to look into `W` and see it's underlying type, which is currently defined to be `Wrapper[A]` as we saw in the beginning. Since the implicit resolution is *recursive*, it now starts looking up an implicit in scope which can help it infer `Wrapper[A]`, and the next implicit definition is `InnerSet`, but it is also defined in terms of `W.Inner! thus we have a cyclic reference and the compiler bails out.

Now, when we define an explicit type for `W`:

```
val W: Wrapped[Int] = new Wrapped(1234)
```

The type checker knows the `W.type` is `Wrapped[Int]` and not `Wrapped[A]`, thus it need not do any recursive implicit resolution. We can see this again in the debug output:

```
|-- Seq[W.Inner] TYPEmode (site: value InnerSeq  in Implicits)                                 
|    |-- scala.`package` EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (site: value InnerSeq  in Implicits)       
|    |    \-> scala.type                                                                       
|    |-- W.Inner TYPEmode (site: value InnerSeq  in Implicits)                                 
|    |    |-- W EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (site: value InnerSeq  in Implicits)                
|    |    |    \-> com.testing.SOTesting.Implicits.W.type (with underlying type Wrapped[Int])  <---- This is the difference
|    |    [adapt] A is now a TypeTree(com.testing.SOTesting.Implicits.W.Inner)                 
|    |    \-> com.testing.SOTesting.Implicits.W.Inner                                          
|    \-> Seq[com.testing.SOTesting.Implicits.W.Inner]
```

Since we now know the underlying `W.type`, the typer can bind `W.Inner` to `Int`, thus find a match for `A`.

Comment: The sad part is that it already knows `A` from the first arg list.

Comment: @som-snytt Yeah, I'm not sure what it doesn't bind `Wrapper` first. Would you say this is a bug or by design?

Comment: I find it strange that it needs to do a lot of work to find out that the type of W is a Wrapped[Int] - it is quite obvious looking at the code. The available implicits don't influence this calculation. And it is very puzzling that it actually works OK with one implicit in scope, but not two.

Comment: Yes, often it's obvious to us but not to the algorithm. I spent some time with the debug output, but Yuval already posted. :) Although "type completers" are somewhat decoupled, that is, lazily evaluated, I don't suppose they have a facility for saying is a type is partially computed by various means. For example, I said A is already determined in this case, but what about cases where A can be X or Y etc. That's determined by the call stack as shown. Tho I suspect that this case could be made to work. (Just supposing.) Thanks for the interesting Q&A.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to this resolution works, but does scalac solves a inferred type every time it's mentioned?

Comment: @pedrofurla It seems that when implicits are required in order to resolve the type, implicit resolution has to kick in to find ones available at scope before completely inferring the proper type.

Comment: As mentioned, the pattern works with one of the implicits in place (the `Seq[W.Inner]`. Is this purely by accident? Just wondering if the pattern should be avoided for future code, in case the type inference algorithm will be adjusted.

Comment: @B.T.Jensen It can work with multiple implicits, just not ones requiring `Wrapper` to be inferred, as you have with `W.Inner`. Once it hits a cyclic reference because it's trying to resolve `Wrapper` multiple times, it bails out. I wouldn't avoid the pattern, just comment the code and make sure a type is defined.

Comment: Having only `implicit val InnerSeq: Seq[W.Inner] = Seq(1,2)` in the scope also refers `W.Inner` (and compiles OK). Why doesn't this result in a cyclic reference error?

Comment: @B.T.Jensen Because the cyclic reference is thrown from the implicit resolution, which starts with `InnerSeq` as the first candidate, not with `Wrapper`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That makes it clear, thanks for the explanation!